# C++ Recursive Search Function (school assignment)

Tags: c++, recursion

For my assignment I have to have two functions (a main function and a recursive helper function) and the purpose is to search for a string within a string then provide the index that string starts at. Example:

String: Hi I am a horse

String to search for: horse

Returns: 10

I have written a program that will do this, but the only problem is in my recursiveHelper function I check the next index by

```
            return recursiveHelper(s.substr(1), t, ++count);
```

which my teacher informs me that string s should not be changed when calling the helper function. Can someone tell me why and also provide me a way to do it as I have been looking all weekend to not avail. Thanks!

Full program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// recursiveHelper function
// purpose: locate the first instance of the string t within the string s
// Parameters: string, string, int
// Returns: int
int recursiveHelper(string s, string t, int count)
{
    // Length variables
    int inputOneLength = s.length();
    int inputTwoLength = t.length();

    // Figure out the base case. Same format as lab10 really
    if (inputOneLength < inputTwoLength)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        // Check the first index -- compare the strings character by character
        if (s.substr(0, inputTwoLength) == t)
        {
            return count;
        }
        else
        {
            // Check the next index
            return recursiveHelper(s.substr(1), t, ++count);
        }
    }
}//end of recursiveHelper

// index_of function
// purpose: locate the first instance of the string t within the string s
// Parameters: string, string
// Returns: int
int index_of(string s, string t)
{
    // Initialize the count
    int count = 0;

    // Send to the helper
    count = recursiveHelper(s, t, count);

    return count;
}//end of index_of

int main()
{
    // Variables
    string inputOne = "";
    string inputTwo = "";

    // Prompt user input
    cout << "This program will find the occurence of one string inside another." << endl;
    cout << "\nEnter the string to be searched: ";
    getline(cin, inputOne);
    cout << "Now enter the string you want to search for: ";
    getline(cin, inputTwo);

    // Pass to index_of function
    int index = index_of(inputOne, inputTwo);

    // Output results
    if (index != -1)
    {
        cout << "The index of substring is = " << index << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Can't find this string." << endl;
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}//end of main
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your teacher is wrong.**
`s` is never changed!

here is the definition of `string::substr()`
`string substr (size_t pos = 0, size_t len = npos)` **const**;

the **const** keyword means the method doesn't change the object. 
you always get a new string from the call to`string::substr()`

Comment: Doesn't the statement s.substr(1) reduce the string, s, by one character?

Comment: No. it creates a new string, which is combined of the second to last character of `s`. as I said, **const** means **No Change To The Object**. this is defined by the language and enforced by the compiler.